# mixin gives error

Tags: d, dmd

The example at: http://www.d-programming-language.org/mixin.html, appears below:

```
template GenStruct(char[] Name, char[] M1) {
    const char[] GenStruct = "struct " ~ Name ~ "{ int " ~ M1 ~ "; }";
} mixin(GenStruct!("Foo", "bar"));
```

"which generates:" (according to the site):

```
struct Foo { int bar; }
```

gives me an error:

`Error: template instance GenStruct!("Foo","bar") GenStruct!("Foo","bar") does not match template declaration GenStruct(char[] Name,char[] M1)`

Is it mine or their bug ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The text is outdated. Replace `char[]` with `string` and it'll work.